# Best approach with ASP.NET Core and Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a small-to-medium sized application in ASP.NET MVC 4 (we call it Portal) and we plan to migrate to something more lightweight and dynamic (like a single page application).

Since our mobile app is in Ionic 1 and we are migrating it to Ionic 2, I want to migrate our Portal to Angular2 as well.

My goal is to find the best approach focusing performance and scalability.

As far as I understand, basically I have two options:

1. Create an ASP.NET Core MVC application and add Angular2 libraries (http://www.centare.com/tutorial-angular2-mvc-6-asp-net-5/)
2. Create an ASP.NET Core application, serve it as a WEB API and create a Angular2 application outside the solution (even using another IDE, like Visual Studio Code) and call that rest web API.

Am I missing the big picture or is it right?
As more experienced guys, what do you advice me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This blog post is missing `Index.html` in wwwroot which, I guess, should be the Home page of the Angular 2 app and Add more subsequent views also in wwwroot which gets data from API(s).

Comment: _Layout.cshtml does the job. Yeah. But I don't know if I should create another website (a WEB API) or put my controllers in the same web site, mixing ASP.NET MVC and Angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think WebApi and SPA should be completely different projects.
When you setup your frontend webserver like nginx you can configure it to serve all /api requests from ASP.NET web api and handle other request through SPA. So it makes clean separation of different layers of you app and allows you to easily add other backend services and frontend SPA apps (if needed) in the future.

Comment: Makes sense. But what about all ASP.NET MVC benefits? Like Razor.
If I decide to create 2 web sites (ASP.NET MVC and an Angular2 app) I will have to replicate my models in Angular2. 
Does it sound wise to you? Or it is indeed the way it should be?

Comment: I think it does not make sense to use MVC and Angular2 at the same time - Angular 2 has very powerful and performant template engine that is more flexible since it works on client. About your models - you only need to replicate simple classes returned by WebApi and you can even automatize generating TypeScript models object from C# objects using http://bridge.net/kb/generate-typescript-definitions/

Comment: I think you`re right. Thank you! That`s what I`ll do.